# Problem displaying options in a selector on a web page: data for loop {{ range }} not being passed in Go template

Tags: html, go

The problem is that on a web page that uses a selector to select a product type, the options (values) inside the selector are not displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Список продуктов</h1>


<form id="addProductForm">
    <label for="productName">Product Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" required>

    <label for="weight">Weight:</label>
    <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" required>

    <label for="typeSelect">Product Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="typeSelect" name="TypeID">
        {{ range .Rows}}
        <option value="{{.ProductType.IDType}}">{{ .ProductType.NameType }}</option>
        {{ end }}
    </select>

    <label for="unit">Unit:</label>
    <input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" required>

    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" required>

    <label for="pricePickup">Price Pickup:</label>
    <input type="number" id="pricePickup" name="pricePickup" required>

    <label for="priceDelivery">Price Delivery:</label>
    <input type="number" id="priceDelivery" name="priceDelivery" required>


    <button type="button" onclick="addProduct()">Add Product</button>
</form>


<table id="productTable">
    <tr>
        <th>ID продукта</th>
        <th>ID типа</th>
        <th>Название продукта</th>
        <th>Вес</th>
        <th>Единица измерения</th>
        <th>Описание</th>
        <th>Цена самовывоза</th>
        <th>Цена с доставкой</th>
    </tr>
    {{range .Rows}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{.ProductID}}</td>
        <td>{{.ProductType.NameType}}</td>
        <td>{{.ProductName}}</td>
        <td>{{.Weight}}</td>
        <td>{{.Unit}}</td>
        <td>{{.Description}}</td>
        <td>{{.PricePickup}}</td>
        <td>{{.PriceDelivery}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{end}}
</table>

<script>
    function addProduct() {
        // Получение данных из формы
        var form = document.getElementById("addProductForm");
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        // Отправка данных на сервер
        fetch("/add_product", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Обработка ответа от сервера
                console.log("Product created:", data);

                // Очистка формы или выполнение других действий при необходимости
                form.reset();
            })
            .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Although this part of the code with the table output works perfectly

```
{{range .Rows}}
<tr>
    <td>{{.ProductID}}</td>
    <td>{{.ProductType.NameType}}</td>
    <td>{{.ProductName}}</td>
    <td>{{.Weight}}</td>
    <td>{{.Unit}}</td>
    <td>{{.Description}}</td>
    <td>{{.PricePickup}}</td>
    <td>{{.PriceDelivery}}</td>
</tr>
{{end}}
```

I want to take the data itself from a table representing such a structure

```
package product_types

type ProductTypes struct {
    IDType   string `json:"type_id"`
    NameType string `json:"type_name"`
}
```

The result of the current code now looks like this

[`result1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cKYC.png)

I tried changing it to this

```
<label for="typeSelect">Product Type:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="typeSelect" name="TypeID">
    {{ range .Rows}}
    <option value="{{.ProductType.IDType}}">{{ .ProductType.NameType }}</option>
    {{ end }}
</select>
```

The result became better, but in the end there were duplicates

[`result2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBXSw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question - I didn’t add the path to the ProductTypes table in app.go

```
} else if req.URL.Path == "/products.html" {
        log.Printf("Обслуживание HTML-файла: %s\n", productsHTMLPath)

        dataRows, err := repoProduct.FindAllProduct(context.TODO()) // Используйте функцию для получения продуктов
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Запрос не выполнен: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        dataRows1, err := repo.FindAll(context.TODO()) // Используйте функцию для получения типов продуктов
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Запрос не выполнен: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(productsHTMLPath)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Не удалось парсирование шаблона: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        Rows := struct {
            Products     []products2.Product
            ProductTypes []product_types2.ProductTypes
        }{
            Products:     dataRows,
            ProductTypes: dataRows1,
        }

        err = tmpl.Execute(res, Rows)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Не удалось выполнить шаблон: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }
```

Initially the code looked like this:

```
} else if req.URL.Path == "/products.html" {
            log.Printf("Обуслуживание HTML-файла: %s\n", productsHTMLPath)

            dataRows, err := repoProduct.FindAllProduct(context.TODO()) // Используйте функцию для получения продуктов
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Запрос не выполнен: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(productsHTMLPath)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Не удалось парсирование шаблона: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
            }

            err = tmpl.Execute(res, struct{ Rows []products2.Product }{dataRows})
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(res, fmt.Sprintf("Не удалось выполнить шаблон: %v", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }
```

product.html:

```
<label for="typeSelect">Product Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="typeSelect" name="TypeID">
        {{ range .ProductTypes}}
        <option value="{{.IDType}}">{{ .NameType }}</option>
        {{ end }}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check Data in Go Template:

Ensure that the data you are passing to the template `({{ range .Rows }})` contains the expected information about product types `({{ .ProductType.IDType }}` and `{{ .ProductType.NameType }})`. You can print the data for debugging purposes:

```
<label for="typeSelect">Product Type:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="typeSelect" name="TypeID">
    {{ range .Rows }}
        <option value="{{ .ProductType.IDType }}">{{ .ProductType.NameType }}</option>
    {{ end }}`enter code here`
</select>
```

#### Debugging in Go Server:

Check the server-side code where you render the HTML template. Ensure that you are fetching and passing the data correctly to the template. You may use `fmt.Println` or logging to inspect the data being passed to the template.

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```